# Testear función que lance una excepción void en java con Mockito

Tags: java, test, mockito

Quiero testear con mockito java una función que lance una excepción, es una funcion void.

```
public void validarSiElUsuarioEsFirmanteCuenta(Usuario usuario) throws FirmanteOperadorException {

    if (!usuarioCuentaDao.usuarioIsFirmante(usuario)) {
        throw new FirmanteOperadorException();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿ Y en qué parte del código del test te falla ?

Comment: No se como testearlo. usando mockito

Comment: Ya te respondí, me gustó tu sinceridad.

Comment: Muchas Graciassssssss!!!!

Comment: @EduBw te hago una consulta, si quiero que el test de verde.. le tendría que pasar un usuario correcto? la funcion es firmante le pega a la base de datos..
Otra pregunta, cuando se le pasa el usuario,, este tendria que estar mockeado? me lanza un null pointer excepcion, la funcion que me mostraste

Comment: Si quieres que sea verde, se tiene que confirmar el método assertEquals, para este caso, que la exception que se lance, sea correcta. El usuario que se le pasa, lo puedes definir tú, por ejemplo new Usuario("menganito") o también Mockito.anyObject() o Mockito.eq(new Usuario("menganito")), así se mockean los usuarios... Finalmente te daba null, porque nunca se le dio memoria a usu y accediste a un método de un objeto sin memoria. Si te ha funcionado, no olvides subir la flecha y darle al verde

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

```
@InjectMocks
InterfazService interfaz; // Si es que el codigo lo tienes en una interfaz

@Test
public void testExceptionNull() { // Cuando se lance este test dará verde porque dio nullPointer.

     Exception myException = null;
     try {
        Usuario usu;  // Vale null, cuando entre a tu función y hagas el usuario. dará el error del nullPointer.
        this.interfaz.validarSiElUsuarioEsFirmanteCuenta(usu); // Supongo que quieres simular que falle
    } catch (Exception e) {
        myException = e;
    }
     assertEquals(myException.getErrorName(), "java.lang.NullPointerException");
}

@Test
public void testExceptionFirmante() {

     Exception myException = null;
     try {
        Usuario usu = new Usuario("menganito"); // No sé la definición de tu clase, tienes que crearte un objeto usuario que no exista para que te entre en el if y te lance tu exception.
        this.interfaz.validarSiElUsuarioEsFirmanteCuenta(usu); // Supongo que quieres simular que falle
    } catch (Exception e) {
        myException = e;
    }
  assertEquals(myException.getErrorName(), "FirmanteOperadorException"); //Lánzalo normal para ver el nombre de la exception, también puedes hacer myException. para ver los métodos que trae la clase Exception.
}
```

Aquí lo único que tienes que hacer con mockito es crear el bean del servicio/interfaz o de donde tengas el código, pero realmente no tienes que usar "Mockito". **Personalmente** yo hablo de usar Mockito para "mockear (un dato falso)" por ejemplo resultados de la base de datos, resultados de otras llamadas a servicios rest, etc.....

Aquí lo único que tienes que hacer es un @test que al capturar el error puedas obtener `FirmanteOperadorException`.

Esta bien pedir ayuda, pero hay que pelearse un poco, además viendo como era la resolución anterior, sólo tenías que modificar unas líneas de código .....

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilicé Mockito solo para la interfaz.

```
public class Main {

UsuarioCuentaDao usuarioCuentaDao;

public void validarSiElUsuarioEsFirmanteCuenta(String usuario) throws FirmanteOperadorException {

    if (!usuarioCuentaDao.usuarioIsFirmante(usuario)) {
        throw new FirmanteOperadorException();
    }
}}
```

La clase de test:

```
public class MainTest {
@Mock
UsuarioCuentaDao usuarioCuentaDao;

@InjectMocks
Main main;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test(expected = FirmanteOperadorException.class)
public void testUsuario() throws FirmanteOperadorException {
    main.validarSiElUsuarioEsFirmanteCuenta("usuario");
    assertNotNull(main);

}}
```